# Hiding/showing actionbar icons depening on webview state not showing consistent behaviour

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**What I am trying to do**
I am showing/hiding two icons in the actionbar, depenending on if the webview can go back or go forward. So only the back action bar icon will be displayed if the webview can go back.

**How I try to do it right now**
After the page has started, I will set the integer to `1` or `0` for back or forward. Depending on if the webview can go back or forward. After that, I call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`

Now `Oncreateoptions..` will hide or show a actionbar item depending on of the value of the integer for back or forward is `1`or `0`.

**How the actionbar and webview are acting with this code**
My app is not showing consistent behaviour. Most of the times, the back item is being displayed if I click a link. The forward item is displayed when I go back, but when I visit another page (so there is nothing to go forward to anymore). It is still being displayed.

**Code**

Declaring variables:

```
int stateForward = 1;
int stateBack = 1;
```

OncreateOptionsmenu:

```
     @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { //this method is used for adding menu items to the Activity
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.webview_menu, menu);
      if (stateBack == 0) //1 is true, 0 is false
      {
          //hide only option 1
          MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.goBack);
          item.setVisible(false);
      }
      else 
      {
          MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.goBack);
          item.setVisible(true);
      }

      if (stateForward == 0) //1 is true, 0 is false
      {
          //hide only option 2
          MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.goForward);
          item.setVisible(false);
      }
      else 
      {
          MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.goForward);
          item.setVisible(true);
      }
      return true;
      }
```

OnOptionsItemSelected

```
    @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { //this method is used for handling menu items' events
      // Handle item selection
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.goBack:
                if(browser.canGoBack()) {
                   browser.goBack();
                }
              return true;

              case R.id.goForward:
                  if(browser.canGoForward()) {
                     browser.goForward();
                  }
              return true;

              default:
                  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
           }
      }
```

onPageStarted

```
   browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,  Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(browser.canGoBack())
            {
                stateBack = 1; 
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            else
            {
                stateBack = 0;
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            if(browser.canGoForward())
            {
                stateForward = 1;
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            else
            {
                stateForward = 0;
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
         }



    });
```

**What it could be**
I'm also feeling that could be that the buttons are 1 step behind my WebView. Example: If I do this respectively in my webview:

```
   Website:    Items that are visible:

  -Website 1 - items not visible
  -Website 2 - items visible of website one (so still nothing)
  -Website 3 - items visible of website two (so the back button)
  -back to website 2 - items visible of website three (so the back button)
  -Website 4 - items visible of "back to website two" (so back and forward buttons)
```

But I'm not 100% sure if this is what is really happening.

Any Idea what is causing this problem, or how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does invalidateOptionsMenu() do?  Does your app show the correct icon states initially - that is, after onCreate()?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu() and yes, initially the correct icons (none to be precisely) are shown, but this is also the default (int = 1)

Comment: oh, sorry. I thought invalidateOptionsMenu() was your code.  Well, it looks like you are doing the right thing with respect to invalidating and creating the icons.  It sounds like you need to set breakpoints in onPageStarted and see whether that code is executing when you expect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `onPageStarted` is being called, and you check if you can go back or can go forward. It will return a value that matches the state "before" onPageStarted. Because only till the next page has been loaded, the state of the webview will be the same.